# THREE.js TypeError: material.onBeforeRender is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I am trying to learn Three.js. But I get an error when trying to run my code. Can someone help me out?

This is the error I get:

```
three.js:19528 Uncaught TypeError: material.onBeforeRender is not a function
    at renderObject (three.js:19528)
    at renderObjects (three.js:19519)
    at renderScene (three.js:19471)
    at WebGLRenderer.render (three.js:19355)
    at tick (hek_3d.js:100)
```

This is my (poorly written) JS code:

```
import {OrbitControls} from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r122/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
import {GLTFLoader} from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r122/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';

// Canvas
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas.display')

// Scene
const scene = new THREE.Scene()

//loader
const loader = new GLTFLoader()
loader.load('includes/3Dhekwerk/assets/test.glb', function(glb){
    console.log(glb)
    const root = glb.scene;
    scene.add(root);
}, function(xhr){
    console.log((xhr.loaded/xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded' )
}, function(error){
    console.log('An error occured')
})

// Objects

// Materials

// Mesh

// Lights

const pointLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1)
pointLight.position.set(2, 2, 5)
pointLight.intensity = 1
scene.add(pointLight)

/**
 * Sizes
 */
const sizes = {
    width: 612,
    height: 723
}

window.addEventListener('resize', () =>
{
    // Update sizes
    sizes.width = 612
    sizes.height = 723

    // Update camera
    camera.aspect = sizes.width / sizes.height
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix()

    // Update renderer
    renderer.setSize(sizes.width, sizes.height)
    renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2))
})

/**
 * Camera
 */
// Base camera
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, sizes.width / sizes.height, 0.1, 100)
camera.position.x = 0
camera.position.y = 0
camera.position.z = 2
scene.add(camera)

// Controls
// const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, canvas)
// controls.enableDamping = true

/**
 * Renderer
 */
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    canvas: canvas,
    alpha: true
})
renderer.setSize(sizes.width, sizes.height)
renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2))
renderer.setClearColor( 0xffffff, 0 )
renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true

/**
 * Animate
 */

const clock = new THREE.Clock()

const tick = () =>
{

    const elapsedTime = clock.getElapsedTime()

    // Update objects
    // Update Orbital Controls
    // controls.update()

    // Render
    renderer.render(scene, camera)

    // Call tick again on the next frame
    window.requestAnimationFrame(tick)
}

tick()


/**
 * OrbitControl
 */

const orbitControl = new OrbitControls(camera,renderer.domElement);
orbitControl.update();
```

HTML

```
<!-- Three.js -->
<script src="lib/three.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="includes/3Dhekwerk/hek_3d.js"></script>

<!-- The Map -->
<canvas class="display"></canvas>
```

Thank you for your time! If anyone could help me out on where to look or what I did wrong, that would be great! I am running this in an index.php with an include. The loading of the glb file seems to work. In the console I get 100% loaded.

Comment: What do you get when you output `console.log(glb)`?

Comment: {scene: Group, scenes: Array(1), animations: Array(0), cameras: Array(0), asset: {…}, …}
animations: []
asset: {generator: 'VISUALIZEGLTF', version: '2.0'}
cameras: []
parser: GLTFParser {json: {…}, extensions: {…}, plugins: {…}, options: {…}, cache: {…}, …}
scene: Group {uuid: '1CB5A48F-F8AF-4F93-BBC1-60A2EA1352C4', name: 'Default', type: 'Group', parent: Scene, children: Array(1), …}
scenes: [Group]
userData: {}
[[Prototype]]: Object

Comment: I highly suspect that the runtime error is produced by the fact that you use library files from different releases. Please try it again with the latest release `r134`.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the help! I have updated the lib files to : import {OrbitControls} from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r132/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
import {GLTFLoader} from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r132/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js'; But I sadly still get the same error

Comment: When I comment out // renderer.render(scene, camera) I don't get the error. So maybe it has to do something with the rendering part? In the Animate section.

Comment: Found it out, I replaced the lib/three.js script with https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r128/three.min.js

Answer (score 2):

Changing the ThreeJS version to 132 worked for me

https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r132/build/three.module.js

Also, using `import maps` really helped

`index.html`

```
<script type="importmap">
    {
        "imports": {
            "three": "https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r132/build/three.module.js"
        }
    }
</script>
<script src="./main.js" type="module"></script>
<canvas id="my-canvas"></canvas>
```

`main.js`

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
```

Comment: solved it for me.